# Node.js and Socket.io app with Apache Cordova not working in android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to follow this simple tutorial [socket-io-with-apache-cordova](https://socket.io/socket-io-with-apache-cordova/) for android with apache cordova. So far I did everything as in the tutorial and I use my own android phone with `android version 8.0` to test the app. When I type the cordova run command app get launched and `shows the screen with "DEVICE IS READY"` and nothing happens. I get this `Received Event: deviceready` message and following errors in the chrome remote debugging console and nothing happens it doesn't pop up an alert like it supposed to.

> localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1549179448883-0:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1549179463998-5 0 ()

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.on('text', function(text) {
                    alert(text);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And when I change `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');` like this with my ip address `var socket = io.connect('http://172.27.180.225:3000');` it doesn't give any errors in the console only this `Received Event: deviceready` message in the console but nothing happens.

index.js file

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();
```

server.js file

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
console.log('socket connected');

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('socket disconnected');
});

socket.emit('text', 'wow. such event. very real time.');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

`index.js and server.js` are located at `www/js` directory
And in `Package.json` I've added these line to start the server

```
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
```

What am i doing wrong ? any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to start the server: Move server.js to the first folder of your project and start it from the command line with "node server.js" or "npm start", as you defined it in Package.json
In the same computer, in another command line, start the project. I did it with "cordova emulate browser"